# HashBytes equivalent in Databricks

Tags: sql-server, databricks, azure-databricks

Is there a SQL Server `hashbyte` equivalent in Databricks? I have a project that migrates data from Databricks database to SQL Server database, I want to make sure that the data transferred is complete by comparing hash. Is there a way to compute hash of a dataframe ?

Comment: If you create a [Linked Server](https://medium.com/@kyle.hale/tutorial-create-a-databricks-sql-linked-server-in-sql-server-668f349d82ef) from your SQL Server instance to your Databricks instance, you can run the `HASHBYTES()` comparison between the transferred data and the source data on Databricks via the Linked Server, within the context of your SQL Server. Note depending on the amount of data in the table in Databricks, this *can* be slow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sql server command: 
`SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR( MAX), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'This is a test.'), 2)`

gives the same result as this sql spark command in Databricks
`SELECT upper( sha2( 'This is a test.', 256))`

just put column name instead of 'This is a test.' and add `FROM table_name`

Comment: SELECT upper(sha2((select column1 from MyTable), 256)) , tried running a similar script with the actual column and table but in returned an error:

[MULTI_VALUE_SUBQUERY_ERROR] More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.

Edit: Im using the SQL Editor to run the script

Comment: [MULTI_VALUE_SUBQUERY_ERROR] is SQL Server error.
 **sha2** is databricks equivalent of sql server **hashbytes** function, it won't work in SQL Server.

For Sql Server you should try something like:
`SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR( MAX), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',  column1), 2) FROM MyTable`